# Joining lines in a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I'VE POSTED AN ANSWER TO THIS BELOW... PLEASE FIND IT. FEEL FREE TO OPTIMIZE IT IF YOU CAN :).

So a brief description of the problem: I've created a file with a massive output from a psql query, and I'm trying to use this data but the format of the output is not ideal. Here is a breakdown of what the data looks like:

> some_date | some_username | some_port | **statement:**
>
> **: SELECT some_query**
>
> some_date | some_username | some_port | statement: SELECT some_different_query

Thats what the data looks like, and the problem is the bold line. I have no idea why that statement is split across two lines like that, but it's screwing with the rest of the processing that I need to do. If I look at the characters in bold section only, it's as follows:

> statement:>$
>
> :> query$

Where `>` is whitespace and `$` is an eol character.

So I really need to join those two lines together, but I have no idea how. This is what I've tried so far:

```
sed 's/\n://g' filename
```

That doesn't work, obviously. Makes sense too, because SED works on a line to line basis I believe. Any suggestions will be gladly appreciated.

Below is a screenshot of the data. I can't copy the data as my VM won't allow it out. Sorry...

[image]

Below is how I'd like this data to look... Try with your awk :P:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. **Some** of the lines are like that? Further, does the word "statement" actually appear in the data?

Comment: Yes, only some... Some are normal, like the third line in the block quote. That one must stay that way.

Comment: `sed 'N;s/\n//' file`

Comment: No that doesn't work... Works for the first line, but if I apply it globally, it eliminates every newline character, putting everything on the same line, which I don't want

Comment: Since this isn't a global problem, there's no global fix -- it's conditional.

Comment: But it is a global problem. That was just a sample set of data. There are around 20 000 lines in the file, and about 7000 are screwed like the example above.

Comment: Take a look at my post again. You'll see a screenshot of what the data looks like.

Comment: Hang on - it looks like you're using sed to do some post-processing of output from a tool named `psql`. Why bother? I mean if the result of running `sed` on the `psql` output is something you still don't want then why not just ask for help writing a tool that converts the original `psql` output to the format you want rather than converting the `sed`-massaged `psql` output? Cut out the middle man. And please stop posting screenshots as they're very close to useless - just give us testable, textual, input and output.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything even marginally more interesting you should be using awk for clarity, simplicity, robustness, portability, and almost every other desirable attribute of software.

Given this sample input file I made up:

```
$ cat file
some_date | some_username | some_port | statement:
: SELECT some_query
:lines and lines
:of stuff...
some_date | some_username | some_port | statement: SELECT some_different_query
some_date | some_username | some_port | statement:
: SELECT something else where
:the quick brown fox
: jumped over
: the lazy
:dog's back
```

this awk command might be what you want:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (NR==1 || sub(/^: */,OFS) ? "" : ORS), $0} END{print ""}' file
some_date | some_username | some_port | statement: SELECT some_query lines and lines of stuff...
some_date | some_username | some_port | statement: SELECT some_different_query
some_date | some_username | some_port | statement: SELECT something else where the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back
```

but I had to make up my own input set to test with so it may not really match your actual input, plus you didn't post any expected output so I'm just guessing.

If not, edit your question to provide a few lines of concrete, testable sample input and expected output.

In case you aren't familiar with awk and other C-like languages, here's what the awk command means:

```
awk '
  {                      # WHILE read the current line ($0) DO
  printf "%s%s",         #   prepare to print 2 strings with no trailing newline
  (NR==1                 #   IF this is the first line of input
  || sub(/^: */,OFS)     #     OR we can replace :<space>* with one space (OFS)
  ?                      #   THEN
  ""                     #     the first string to print is NULL
  :                      #   ELSE
  ORS                    #     the first string to print is a newline (ORS)
  )                      #   ENDIF
  , $0                   #   the second string to print is the current input line
  }                      # ENDWHILE
  END{print ""}          # print a newline (ORS) at the end of the output
' file
```

The part commented as IF..ENDIF is just a common ternary expression as used in many languages, and OFS and ORS are awk builtin variables than contain the Output Field Separator and Output Record Separator strings (by default a single space and a newline respectively).

Comment: Really useful answer... Thank you :). Like the broken down explanation too.

Comment: You're welcome. Serioulsly, no exageration - any time you find yourself using sed language constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n), stop as you are using constructs that had a purpose when sed was first invented in the early 1970s but became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented. people only play with them today for the mental challenge, not to actually use them in real software. The awk equivalent will always be clearer, more robust, portable and maintainable, and will usually be more efficient and often briefer too.

Comment: Funny you mention efficiency... That sed command with the 3 parts below was crazy slow haha.

Comment: So for the purpose of trying it out, I tried it out... Doesn't work. Your awk made the whole 360k line file into 1 line :P. In the interest of fair play, I'll put a screenshot of some of the data on my question. Maybe try again?

Comment: Please just post some concrete, testable, sample input and expected output. As I said in my answer, I had to invent some sample input so you may need to massage the answer to work with whatever your real input is. We can't tell from a screenshot where linewraps are in the text or in the display, nor can we tell prompts from data, etc. If you post something we can test against then we can help you come up with the exact answer. If your VM won't let you copy/paste it then type it because the alternative is that WE have to type it and we're more likely to get it wrong than you are.

Comment: @RyanCauldwell btw - the ONLY 2 ways that the awk command I posted could convert any file into a single line are: 1) The input file was already a single line, or 2) Every line in the file (except optionally the first) starts with a `:`. The reason for that is that for the 2nd and subsequent input lines, if the current line does not start with `:` then the script **WILL** print a newline before the current line. Maybe check your input file for missing newlines? control-Ms instead of newlines? Other issues? `cat -v file` will help you see control chars, and `dos2unix` might be useful to fix them

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/: $/{s///;N;s/\n: //;ba' -e '}' YourFile
```

Try this to regroup lines ending with your cutting delimiter (and removing it)

The `N` load a new line to current buffer, so you could work on multi line and treat newline as normal character

with new info where there is 1 line ending with `:` and following stating with 
`: \ but not ending with previous delimiter

```
sed -e 's/: $//;1h;1!H;$!d' -e 'x;s/\n: //g' YourFile
```

Comment: Didn't work... I've attached a screenshot to my original post

Comment: add a second sed for this second interpretation (based on you sample)

Comment: Making progress :). I'm clearly not very good at SED, because everything I've tried after your line just doesn't join up the rest of the problem lines. Posted a second screenshot now. So sorry. So now I need to find a way of joining lines that end with ", " and starting with ":"

Answer (score 0):

So it's not pretty, but I found an answer :). There are probably ways to make this line considerably shorter, and I'd appreciate any responses on how to do so, I love learning new ways of doing things. This is the answer:

```
sed ':x; /\:$/ { N; s/\:\n//; tx }' temp.txt | sed ':x; /\, $/ { N; s/\n\://; tx }' | sed ':x; /.\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/ { N; s/\n\://; tx }'
```

Hope I didn't copy that down wrong. A short explanation, for anybody that wants to use a similar instance down the line. The first part looks for all lines which end with `:` and replaces the newline character and first `:` of the next line. The second part looks for all lines which end with `,` and replaces the newline character there and the `:` of the next line. The last part finds all lines that end with any normal character or number (hence `[a-zA-Z0-9]`) and removes the newline character as well as the `:` of the next line.

Complicated (for me at least :) ), but fun.

Thanks for all the responses.

**EDITED 2015-09-22**

I managed to get that horribly long sed command down to a 'simpler' one liner:

```
sed -e ':loop' -e ':x; /.\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)$/ { N; s/\n\://; tx }' -e 'b loop'
```

Works for every case I've found so far :). The awk answer I've marked as the answer is still the easiest though.

-Ryan

Comment: At some point writing that it must've occurred to you that you might be using the wrong tool for the job. You are - use awk instead.

Comment: I replied to your answer already... For interests sake, I played around with the sed command, and got it down to a 'simpler' line as well. Appended to my post above now.

Comment: It is briefer but still horrible ;-). I expect you'd find it doesn't work with some seds and it's probably slow and try adding to it to do anything at all (e.g. print a count of the lines concatenated to stderr, or skip lines that contain some string, or .....). There's just no point  trying to use sed for anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines, other than the mental exercise.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/:\n:/:/;P;D' file
```

or if the line is split into multiple lines:

```
sed ':a;N;s/:\n:/:/;ta;P;D' file
```